# What is graph automorphism and graph homomorphism

Tags: graph-theory

I know what is graph isomorphism [these are isomorpic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkXio.gif)

But what is graph automorhpism and  graph homomorphism in a simple way, can you post an example of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Homomorphisms** are the most general structure preserving maps between graphs. You can map any vertex to any other *as long* as everything which is connected before is also connected afterwards.

For example take a bipartite graph $G=(A\cup B,E)$. We can map this graph into the single-edge-graph $G'=(\{a,b\},\{\{a,b\}\})$ with only two vertices $a$ and $b$ connected by an edge $\{a,b\}$. A possible homomorphism is

$$\phi(v)=\begin{cases}a&\text{for $v\in A$}\\b&\text{for $v\in B$}\end{cases}.$$

*Isomorphisms* are special homomorphisms which are invertible and for which the inverse is a homomorphism too. The difference to general homomorphisms is that you now must pay additional attention that anything which is *not* connected before must be *not* connected afterwards. Something which is not necessary for general homomorphisms.

**Automorphisms** are special isomorphsism which map from a graph to the same graph. For example, an automorhism of the cycle $C_n:=\{\Bbb Z_n,\{\{i,i+1\}\mid i\in\Bbb Z_n\}\}$ has the automorphism $\phi(i)=i+1$. It can be interpreted as a rotation of the cycle graph.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that, sir. But is it possible to see a pure example like a picture or something? I still have a little bit of misunderstanding

Comment: @AlexMIEL Have you checked out the [wikipedia page on graph  homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_homomorphism)? The first picture might be a good example. If this is not helping I can add pictures if I find time for it. But explain what you are not understanding.

Comment: I actually understood everything. Thanks alot for your help, especially wikipedia was very helpful.